# A generic error occurred in GDI+ while saving Image using Image.Save(Filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Following is my code to save image using,

```
HttpPostedFile postedFile = request.Files[file];

string directoryPath = @"~\PostImage\";  

Image image = Image.FromStream(postedFile.InputStream);

string Filepath = Server.MapPath(directoryPath);

string Filename = Filepath + "PostImageFile.jpg";

result.FieldName = Filename;

image.Save(Filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I am getting error at `image.Save(Filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution,
First I created folder at my local machine **"PostedImages"** in application directory.
Then in **Properties** of folder in **"Security"** tab added three new users
1) IIS_USRS
2) IUSR
3) NETWORK SERVICE
For all these users given FullControl access rights each user.
Then added that folder in application and published to Azure.
Now, everything works fine.
Code changed like:

```
string Filepath = Server.MapPath(@"~\PostedImages\");  
string FilenameServer = Filepath + "PostedImage.jpg";
Image img = Image.FromStream(postedFile.InputStream);
Bitmap bmp = img as Bitmap;
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
Bitmap bmpNew = new Bitmap(bmp);
g.DrawImage(bmpNew, new System.Drawing.Point(0,0));
g.Dispose();
bmp.Dispose();
img.Dispose();
bmpNew.Save(FilenameServer, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I got solution from http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/159114/Error-when-hosted-in-IIS-Server-SystemRuntimeInteropServicesExternalException-0x80004005-A-generic-error-occurred-in-GDI/